# adb is not installed or is not configured properly

Tags: android-studio, nativescript, ubuntu-16.04

ally-super-app@ally-super-app:~$ tns doctor
✔ Getting environment information

There seem to be issues with your configuration.
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
⚠ Update available for component nativescript. Your current version is 5.3.1 and the latest available version is 5.3.3.
✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
✔ The Android SDK is installed.
✔ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
✔ Local builds for iOS can be executed only on a macOS system. To build for iOS on a different operating system, you can use the NativeScript cloud infrastructure.
✖ WARNING: adb from the Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.
 For Android-related operations, the NativeScript CLI will use a built-in version of adb.
To avoid possible issues with the native Android emulator, Genymotion or connected
Android devices, verify that you have installed the latest Android SDK and
its dependencies as described in http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements

You have nativescript-cloud extension installed, so you can execute cloud builds, but your environment is not configured properly and you will not be able to execute local builds. To continue, choose one of the following options: 
Select "Sync to Playground" to enjoy NativeScript without any local setup. All you need is a couple of companion apps installed on your devices.
Select "Configure for Local Builds" to run the setup script and automatically configure your environment for local builds.
Select "Skip Step and Configure Manually" to disregard this option and install any required components manually.
? To continue, choose one of the following options:  Skip Step and Configure Manually

ally-super-app@ally-super-app:~$ tns doctor
✔ Getting environment information

There seem to be issues with your configuration.
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
⚠ Update available for component nativescript. Your current version is 5.3.1 and the latest available version is 5.3.3.
✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
✔ The Android SDK is installed.
✔ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
✔ Local builds for iOS can be executed only on a macOS system. To build for iOS on a different operating system, you can use the NativeScript cloud infrastructure.
✖ WARNING: adb from the Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.
 For Android-related operations, the NativeScript CLI will use a built-in version of adb.
To avoid possible issues with the native Android emulator, Genymotion or connected
Android devices, verify that you have installed the latest Android SDK and
its dependencies as described in http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements

You have nativescript-cloud extension installed, so you can execute cloud builds, but your environment is not configured properly and you will not be able to execute local builds. To continue, choose one of the following options: 
Select "Sync to Playground" to enjoy NativeScript without any local setup. All you need is a couple of companion apps installed on your devices.
Select "Configure for Local Builds" to run the setup script and automatically configure your environment for local builds.
Select "Skip Step and Configure Manually" to disregard this option and install any required components manually.
? To continue, choose one of the following options:  Skip Step and Configure Manually

✖ WARNING: adb from the Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.

Answer (score -3):

### Run on terminal below line it will work

export ANDROID_HOME=/root/Android/Sdk